# APScheduler logger for scheduller and executor

Tags: python-3.x, logging, apscheduler

In my application i have to use apscheduler. I set logger for BackgroundScheduler like this:

```
self.schedlogger = logging.getLogger("gwserver.{}.sched".format(type(self).__name__))
self.schedlogger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
self.sched = BackgroundScheduler(logger=self.schedlogger)
self.sched.start()
```

And indeed scheduler uses proper logger. But executor inside scheduler still uses default one.
To overcome this i had to add one line to the code above:

```
self.sched._executors['default']._logger = self.schedlogger
```

But it's looks like a dirty hack for me. Is it any proper way to set logger for both scheduler and executor?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is hardcoded in BaseExecutor.start:

```
def start(self, scheduler, alias):
    """
    Called by the scheduler when the scheduler is being started or when the executor is being added to an already
    running scheduler.

    :param apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler scheduler: the scheduler that is starting this executor
    :param str|unicode alias: alias of this executor as it was assigned to the scheduler
    """

    self._scheduler = scheduler
    self._lock = scheduler._create_lock()
    self._logger = logging.getLogger('apscheduler.executors.%s' % alias)
```

See: https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/c534d51a57638e8a8a51c36d4a4128b89f8beb22/apscheduler/executors/base.py?at=master

Comment: As for me, i prefer that, by default, executor have the same logger as a scheduler. I have dozen of loggers and all logs are writen to stdout so it hard for me to read useful logs through all "INFO" logs from executor.